# Spontaneously Broken Symmetries

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry-breaking

Weinberg Chapter 19, QFT 2, opens with the following argument for spontaneous symmetry breaking (section 19.1):

- The states with minimum expectation value of $H$ are given by the minima of effective potential (section 16.3). So, vacuum states correspond to minima of effective potential or $-\Gamma[\phi]$, say for $\phi = const$. Let's say that a state with VEV $\bar{\Phi}$ correspond to the minima; however, this state is not invariant under symmetry transformation, so it generates on the transformation another states which has the same minimum value for the potential because $\Gamma[\phi] = \Gamma[L\phi]$. We basically get the degenerate vacua.
- For simple discrete symmetry ($\phi \rightarrow - \phi$), we will get two states in which field VEV is $\bar{\phi}$ and $-\bar{\phi}$ for which we get the potential minima.
- However, we can't declare victory and say that we have the spontaneous breaking of this symmetry yet. Because in principle, we can get a state that is a superposition of the two states $|VAC, \pm>$ which is actually invariant under the symmetry. Basically, if the two states $|VAC, \pm>$ are degenerate, we can have a linear superposition of these states in the degenerate subspace, which might actually preserves symmetry, and there is no symmetry breaking.

> But we constrained the field expectation in the vacuum states to be at the minima of the effective potential, however, a general superposition just breaks this constraint. So, how can a general superposition be considered a possible vacuum state?

Comment: The two states are indeed degenerate, at least in the infinite system limit. However, even when you can form the two states $|\text{vac}, \pm\rangle$, the symmetry is still broken because these two states do not satisfy cluster decomposition.

Comment: Thanks, I understand SSB; my question is about the vev of field in the superposition state, which is required to be minima of V(\phi), unless $<-|\phi|+> \approx 0$ as well (which I think is the the case), this condition is not satisfied.

Comment: The vev of field in the superposition state is 0, as required by the symmetry. In this case, the condition that it needs to be the minimum only applies to the states that satisfy cluster decomposition.